# TOC entry and PDF bookmark for colophon do not match

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, bookmarks

I am compiling a book in `memoir` class using `xelatex` and am having problems getting the TOC entry and PDF bookmark to match. Moreover, both point to the wrong page. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
%
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
    \section{Sample}
    Here is some text.
\chapter{Two}
    \section{Follow up}
    Here is some more text.
\chapter{Three}
    \section{More follow up}
    Here is still more text.
\backmatter
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
{\centering\Large\bfseries Colophon\\}
\noindent This is the start of the colophon.
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Colophon}
\end{document}
```

I wish the Colophon to be at the same level as a chapter in both the TOC and the PDF bookmark hierarchy.

Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `\phantomsection`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}
    \section{Sample}
    Here is some text.
\chapter{Two}
    \section{Follow up}
    Here is some more text.
\chapter{Three}
    \section{More follow up}
    Here is still more text.

\backmatter

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Colophon}%
{\centering\Large\bfseries Colophon\par}
\noindent This is the start of the colophon.
\end{document}
```

`\bookmarksetup` is not needed, because the level is set by `\addcontentsline`

Comment: Thank you @egreg. It works perfectly! I wonder why this very useful `\phantomsection` command is not more prominently documented.

Comment: It is even mentioned in the memoir manual. Memoir uses it in several places even when `hyperref` is not used.